# How does Facebook implement Attach Link

Tags: java, html

*Facebook* can (almost) always extract the most important text content and images from the page. I think a common parsing rule cannot do this.

How does *Facebook* implement it? 
Has it prepared the rules for parsing links from popular sites?
Or there is a smarter way to find out real content from html?

Answer (score 0):

Meta tags. Many websites will even optimize for facebook by using open graph `og` `<meta>` tags. Even those that don't use `og` will often have `<meta>` tags with useful information like summaries, title, image, etc.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/

So to answer your question - they don't. The websites do it for them.

Comment: I understand that some information could get from <meta> headers.   And I think it is a reasonable solution for most web site.   However, fb, linked, google+ they did much better job than that.   let's take a look LinkedIn, and attached SO's About page, (http://stackoverflow.com/about)     You can see, it extracted the most important text and image out.  It skipped text and image in top banner, logo and nav bar. However, there is no special <meta> tag or other header in SO's About page.  They even didn't use <title> but parse it out from web content smartly.